# How to query on manay to many relation in LINQ to Enities?

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, many-to-many

I have a many to many relation, yd_Category creates a tree , every article exist in one or more category, i want to get all articles exists in a given category id and all sub categories?

how to do that in Linq to entities?

you can check entity relations on below links:

Comment: http://www.uploadimage.co.uk/images/381074Capture2.PNG

Comment: http://www.uploadimage.co.uk/images/823877Capture.PNG

Answer (score 1):

That is quite difficult because Linq-to-entities doesn't support hierarchical queries. So if you have theoretically unlimited depth of category hierarchy you need to do this in SQL by using table expressions and hierarchical queries and expose that query to your application either as view (if possible) or stored procedure (table valued functions are not yet supported in 4.x).